# How can I debug the interaction between two contracts?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have a solidity file that has:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract World {
    mapping (address => bool) players;
    mapping (address => ResourceBank) resourceBanks;
    function giveZero() public {
        if (!players[msg.sender]) {
            resourceBanks[msg.sender] = new ResourceBank();
            players[msg.sender] = true;
        }
        ResourceBank bank = resourceBanks[msg.sender];
        bank.add(0);
    }
}

contract ResourceBank {
    uint[] resources;
    function add(uint resource) public {
        resources.push(resource);
    }
}
```

When I deploy and run `giveZero` the first time, it is fine. On the second invocation of `giveZero` on the same contract, the transaction is failing and getting reverted but I do not know why.

I am using [remix.ethereum.org](http://remix.ethereum.org). I debug the transaction and am taken to the `bank.add(rewardType)` line. I've read lots of documentation but still do not know how to investigate this. I have tried sending gas along with the `add` call but it is not helping. The `add` method can be called many times without an issue when I deploy a separate `ResourceBank`.

What is going wrong here and how can I debug the issue?

Comment: It appear to be a bug with remix. It does works correctly with truffle and its private testnet, also tried with a geth private testnet and work there also.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael. I came to the same conclusion. So I started using testRPC but then ran into a different bug on there. The issue that I had on testRPC did not throw on a geth private testnet. This whole experience has been frustrating. If I want to continue smart contract development, I feel like I must use a private testnet. I guess the tooling is not completely there.